# Is there syntax for declaring character literals in hexadecimal notation?

Tags: rust, char, hex, literals

Something like

```rust
const X: char = '0x10FFFC';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use `\u{..}`:

```rust
const X: char = '\u{10FFFC}';
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ecb31127d3b00a27f80745f814e33bf0)

One trick for this cases is play with the compiler. If you try the following code it will give you a nice hint about what to do for example:

```
const X: char = 0x10FFFC as char;
```

```
error: only `u8` can be cast into `char`
 --> src/lib.rs:1:17
  |
1 | const X: char = 0x10FFFC as char;
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use a `char` literal instead: `'\u{10FFFC}'`
  |
  = note: `#[deny(overflowing_literals)]` on by default
```